# Ajax directly going to error function? following is my code

Tags: jquery, ajax, syntax-error

**this is my HTML code
 when blur event fire it is showing error,the page is also there, and all it directly goes to the error block and alert error message**

> this the HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="input_email" class="form-control" id="email">
                            <div id="email_error_block" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>  <span id="email_error_text"></span>
```

> this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {                  
                    $('#email').blur(function () {
                          var email = $("#email").val();
                          alert(email);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo $url ?>dbOp/organization_detail.php',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {
                                email: email,
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert('requesting');
                                if (data == 1) {

                                    $('#email_error_text').html('email Already exist');
                                    $('#email_error_block').fadeIn();
                                } else {
                                    $('#email_error_block').hide();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('error while requesting');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Comment: check the url in ajax

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code try to print you url it may be wrong

Comment: @NITINPATEL actually it was datatype issue, which was i am sending and receiving bad way.i had just commented 'datatype' that its done!

Answer (score 0):

Fix error block code to:

```
error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

And see what the message says.
Also - If I had to guess, I'd say the URL part is corrupted.
Try hardcoding the URL and see what happens.
And for the future - embedding PHP code inside JavaScript code is bad practice.

Comment: thank you                                                                                                                i'll be take care for that(embeding php).